# ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group

Tags: python

I came across this method in Python:

```
ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group
```

In the description, it mentioned:

```
Create a mutually exclusive group.
```

What does a `mutually exclusive group` mean in this context? Is there a simple example that clarifies this?

Thanks.

Comment: It means you can add arguments to the mutually exclusive group. For instance if `-a` and `-b` are in the group, you can supply either `-a` or `-b`, but not both. Take a look at Mutual exclusion here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) has an explanation (emphasis mine):

> Create a mutually exclusive group. `argparse` will make sure that **only one** of the arguments in the mutually exclusive group was present on the command line.